# Can't specify update from table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to make an SQL update request from multiple tables. I have  3 tables - `users`, `timesheets` and `projetstaches`.

I need to take the last recorded `prtTimeSheetID` of my `usrid`, which is 7.

So I tried;

```
UPDATE  `timesheets` SET  `timVerified` = 0   WHERE  `prtTimeSheetId` =  
(SELECT MAX(  `prtTimeSheetId` ) 
FROM `projetstaches`  WHERE usrId = 7 AND `timId` = prtTimeSheetId AND `timUserId` = usrID)
```

The error message is: #1054 - Unknown column 'prtTimeSheetId' in 'where clause'

How I do I specify that `prtTimesheetId` comes from the `projetstaches` table?

Comment: is it mysql, or another dbms ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus mysql sorry for the delay and forget to specify

Comment: And is the `prtTimeSheetID` column present in `timesheets`?

Comment: In your query, column references are not qualified with table names, which makes it difficult to work with the query and find an appropriate solution. Please consider specifying which columns come from which table. Also, it would help to know the kind of relationship between the two tables (1:N, N:1, N:N).

Comment: Or better yet - supply DDLs for all these tables.